# Simple ajax cart based on selection from radio options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

As you can see below I have a simple table with radio buttons, now what i'm attempting to do is when that radio button is selected i can update another part of the page which will contain the table contents and a pay/book button.
[image]

So that once i have selected that radio button the contents from that row will be available here:
[image]

Now my aim is to do this with AJAX but i'm not completely sure how i can go about it in terms of it updates when the option is selected. Should i use a basic ajax function that is activated on the on change of a radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following

```
$("#radioButton 1, #radioButton2, ...").click(function (){
    if ($(this).prop('checked', true)){ //I guess that the prop is already set to checked when this if is called because were calling the click function
        $.ajax({
            //do your call to the data you need
        })
        .done(function(response(){
            //display it
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        });
    }
    else{
        //hide elements
    }
})
```

As you can see above you need to set the id's for the radio buttons seperated with comma

If this you're displaying it in some sort of list you could select the radioButtons with child selectors as far as i know

This code isn't tested, but it should work like this, exept i made a typo.

**EDIT**

If you want this function to be set to all radiobuttons on that page you could do the following:

```
$(":radio").click(function (){ // a selector for the type of the element
    //Here comes the action from above
}
```

I think you also could only do this for all radio buttons from a certain div like

```
$("nameofthediv :radio").click(function (){
    //Here comes the action from above
}
```

I tested this in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wd5Yu/3/) The alert only comes up by radiobuttons within the div

Comment: Thanks, yeah it should be .success not .done :) but thanks

Comment: No, this is just another way to do it, in fact jQuery Ajax works with Promisses itself, so it matches `success` and `error` to `.done` and `.fail`. Both way work fine, i prefer this one :)

Comment: That's true indeed :D

Comment: for (i = 0; i <= <?php echo $x; ?>; i++) {
  $("#radio"+[i]).click(function (){
     if ($(this).prop('checked', true)){ 
      $.ajax({
          //do your call to the data you need
        })
        .done(function(response(){
            //display it
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        });
     }
     else{
         //hide elements
     }
  });
 }

Comment: Sorry, as my radio buttons are generated in PHP based on rows from a database, how could i call the contents within ajax through the way i am looping through the radio buttons? :/

Comment: What does `<?php echo $x; ?>;` stand for? The number of RadioButtons you generate?

Comment: yeah so for example at the moment it's 21 cus the database generated 21 rows.

Comment: Thanks that's great can i target $.ajax({ that isn't directly from the form input but contents within the div it's contained in?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you mean. Can you add some code or something to explain it? I also added a jsFiddle for the `div :radio` selector

Comment: Basically inside the <tr> in side the form as you can see from my image i have information such as venue name, capacity, price ect i'm looking to use $.ajax to pull that information in place it in my booking information container. How can i do this?